# Python list of strings in dataframe

Tags: python

I have a dataframe columns entries that looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhaSX.png)
how can I clean it so that when I count the number of unique values it doesn't count [authorized], [authorized, distribution] and [distribution, authorized] as 3 different categories?

I tried df['cust_industry'].str.strip() and replace method but it didn't work!

so the column cust_industry contains the customer industry, one customer may have more than one industry so each row contains an array of strings in the following shape: –
["Maintenance & Repair","Authorized Distributor"], and I want it to be like:{'Maintinance & Repair' , 'authorized distributer'}
I wrote the following code:

```
df['cust_industry'] = df['cust_industry'].str.capitalize()
df['cust_industry'] = df['cust_industry'].fillna('Other')
# df['cust_industry'] = df['cust_industry'].str.replace("'" , '"')
# df['cust_industry'] = df['cust_industry'].str.replace('"' , "'")
# df['cust_industry'] = df['cust_industry'].str.replace('\W', ' ', regex=True)
# df['cust_industry'] = df['cust_industry'].str.strip().capitalize()
# df['cust_industry'] = df['cust_industry'].str.strip(" Don t Know")
spec_chars = ["!",'"',"#","%","&","'","(",")",
              "*","+",",","-",".","/",":",";","<",
              "=",">","?","@","[","\\","]","^","_",
              "`","{","|","}","~","–"]
for char in spec_chars:
    df['cust_industry'] = df['cust_industry'].str.replace(char, ' ')
>> The output was like this:

    

0                  authorized distributor  
1                  authorized distributor  
2                            contract mfg  
3                            contract mfg  
4           industrial   telecom  datacom
```

for example I want the 4th line to output:{'Industrial' , 'telecom' , 'datacom'}
Finally what I want Is when I write the following code:

```
df['cust_industry'].unique()
```

industries = df.groupby(df['cust_industry'])['controlnumber'].count()
industries

the answer is :

```
authorized  100
distribution 90
.
.
.
```

Not as the following:

```
authorized 20
distribution 30
authorized distribution 100
```

Sorry I know the question is messy...

Comment: provide full code that you tried and the results you expect to see.

Comment: I get it that you want `['Authorized Distributor']`, `['Authorized Distributor', 'Contract Mfg']` and `['Contract Mfg', 'Authorized Distributor']` to counted as one. In which case: (1) How do you differentiate `authorized` and `distribution`, given that there are only strings? (2) There is a row consists of three elements in your data. Does the original rule apply, and, if yes, how? Please answer these questions by providing full code and expected results, as advised by Vagner.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 0
for value in values:
    if not any(value == [authorized], value == [authorized, distribution], value ==[distribution, authorized]):
        a += 1
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I have a large number of categories, and 800k row so for loop won't do :(